# Plot of Probability of Cancer vs Test Sensitivity

Tags: bayesian, sensitivity-specificity

I'm looking at the following problem and its solution and am really struggling to understand how they came up with the necessary values.

> My Questions

1, For part (a) we are asked to plot $y=P(C|+)$ as a function of $x=P(+|C)$ given that P(C)=0.01. The formula (3.87) can then be translated to $y=\frac{0.01x}{0.01x + 0.99P(+|NC)}$. I don't know what they use for $P(+|NC)$, nor how it could produce the blue straight line graph that they claim in the solution? I have a similar question about how changing 0.01 to 0.3 will be able to produce the orange curve since it doesn't appear to change the $x$ dependence?

2, Similar problem to above for the second graph - I don't see how we have all the values? Here we use $x=P(+|NC)$ but we don't have $P(+|C)$?

3, The claim is that the third graph uses $y=P(C|+)$ and $x=P(C)$ using $P(+|C)=0.9$ and $P(+|NC)=1-0.92=0.08$. Plotting it on WolframAlpha I get something similar so I can believe this one. However, I would like some explanation of the third paragraph on page 13 which says the biggest information gain is when $P(C) \sim 0.3$. Presumably this is because there is the biggest "gap" between blue and black curves? And since the black curve corresponds to assigning $P(C|+)=P(C)$ it is basically a useless test that adds no info, right?

**

> The Original Question and Solution

**

[image]

Comment: can you share the source? and there is a typo in (1), $1-x$ should be $0.99$

Comment: @gunes fixed typo and see page 13 on here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://study.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/chapter3.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjfp6OH0tngAhWFLn0KHS2MDwYQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1WPsVT_Y2gWJbe0cABfsNL

Comment: @gunes presumably we need to guess a value for P(+|NC) in terms of x? I can't see how we would work it out using e.g. a Venn diagram...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you missed the general information given in the sub-section beginning, i.e. sub-section $3.8$ (Page 12). That paragraph makes a general statement valid for all questions under section $3.8$ unless stated otherwise. So, you'll assume FPR = 0.08, which is the missing information in part (a), i.e. $P(+|NC)$. I've used $P(+|NC)=0.08$, plotted your equation, and obtained same graph given in the solution:

[image]

Again, for (2), you have $P(+|C)$ value given as $0.9$.
For (3), your comment is correct. It has the biggest gap around $P(C)\approx 0.3$ and this gap represents the information you've gained by applying the test vs no-test.